# SharePoint Designer Workflows - stuck or stopped running

Tags: sharepoint-designer

The workflow does not display any error messages, but they just wouldn't move forward after 'starting.'  - they were all working yesterday and no changes occurred.  I tried manually terminating and this doesn't even work. The system seems to 'run' after clicking the [end workflow] but the workflow remains as is. Any idea?

This is on SharePoint Online and SPD 2013

Answer (score 0):

Have your admins check the workflow timer job to make sure it is not stuck or stopped.  You can also check yourself to see if the workflow has made it through the timer service by checking the workflow history list.  This is a hidden list so you have to get to it directly from the URL.

```
http://[servername]/[sitename]/lists/Workflow%20History
```

Comment: I'm using SharePoint Online and not sure where to check for the timer job. I went to the workflow history and no workflow made it since this morning (business hours). Last run was from 5:30am which I'm assuming due to the 'pause' in the workflow from yesterday's.